# How to play the avi video file in a new browser using html code

Tags: java, html, css, video, avi

I have the video url, i try to play that video , but it is not playing, it is downloaded. How to play the video

```
<div> For help <a href="https://xxx/xxx.avi" target="_blank">Watch this video</a></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't embed video in an anchor tag, you have to use the  html5 tag.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="https://xxx/xxx.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="https://xxx/xxx.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

You can find more info in http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video

Hope it helps.

Comment: P.S   here the src="movie.mp4" but my video file is not in server, i have only the video url

Comment: @Andres Thomposon it is a third party video , we cant change the format

Comment: @AndrewThompson I agree, it was just the first link it came on google.
chakri just put the whole url in your video https://xxx/xxx.avi